# Removing <li> indent

Tags: html, css

How can i remove the indent that comes after the bullet point in a  in html? it is as if the text is growing from the center out rather from the left to the right.

```css
#listCont ul{
font-family:"Myriad Pro", sans-serif;
size: 14px ;
color: #222 ;
padding: o ;
margin: 0 ;
}

#listCont ul li {
padding-left: opx ;
margin-left: 0px ;
text-indent: opx ;
}
```

```html
<p>Un-indented Text</p>

<ul id="listCont">
  <li>Beef Lasange</li>
  <li>Shepards Pie</li>
  <li>Chicken Curry</li>
  <li>Boiled Bacon Dinner</li>
  <li>Corned Beef Dinner</li>
  <li>Turkey and Ham Dinner</li>
  <li>Roast Beef Dinner</li>
  <li>Chicken Dinner</li>
  <li>Chciken and Gravy 2pk</li>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: You have a typo, `#listCont {...}`, not `#listCont ul {...}`.

Comment: You have a second typo, `padding: o` must be `padding: 0`.

Comment: You have even more typos involving using an o where what you want is a 0. What are you doing? Apply some basic care when coding stuff!